# Using different functions pythontically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a Twitterbot, mostly for fun. It works, but I've been automating through bash, using:

```
python -c "import twitterbot; twitterbot.good_morning_tweet()"
```

As a scheduled task. Let's say I have a bunch of functions like this: good_afternoon_tweet(), don't_forget_to_hydrate_tweet(), etc.

I'm relatively inexperienced and wanted to use `__main__`, but I'm not sure how. I could use `datetime` and have the program constantly check the time. Is that the pythonic way to do this? Is that more efficient? Thank you

Comment: One approach would be to use a **scheduler**, such that functions are registered to be called “at such and such a time”. Using real the date/time is merely how the scheduler knows to call the appropriate functions, which have been previously registered with rules.. CRON is a type of scheduler, albeit one that works by launching new processes. In the case of CRON the “functions” are the programs to execute. There are similar schedulers (libraries) that can run entirely from within a Python process itself.

Comment: To implement a simple scheduler manually really just requires a list of (next_run_time, function_to_run, interval) entries. If the list is sorted by next run time then, each “scheduler loop”, say after pausing a second in a while-true, simply compare the times — if the time is exceeded, remove the item from the front, execute the function, and enqueue it again with the next execution time.

Comment: Or.. just use an existing (Python) **scheduler / “cron”** library that already takes care of all the details — https://pypi.org/search/?q=scheduler ,  https://pypi.org/search/?q=cron might be starts.

Comment: I appreciate it